# How deep can a virtual machine like VirtualBox emulate Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, c, emulation, firmware, virtualization

Currently I have the firmware code for a device running on Raspberry Pi. I want to use a linux computer that I have to test the device out using a virtual machine like Virtual Box (To connect it to server for example).

So my question is, to what extent can raspberry pi's functions be emulated by a virtual machine, compared to bare metal? What are the things a RPI system running on bare metals can do, that a virtual machine-emulated RPI cannot do? Can the emulator do firmware code testing, and server testing, for example?

Comment: QEMU is known to work, but virtualbox does not support the PI. One limitation will be that you can not interact with the GPIO pins.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Can I run multiple instances of Raspberry Pi (so I can have multiple RPIs connecting to a server) with my computer? I will try QEMU. Thanks!

Comment: I have not tried it but I don't see why not.